# Вживання слова “доброволець” в діловій документації

Tags: вживання-слів, стилістика

Підкажіть, чи допускається вживати слово "доброволець" в діловій документації.
Коли почав шукати, то натрапляю скрізь тільки на досить лаконічне визначення.

В офіційних документах, відповідно до положень Закону України «Про військовий обов’язок та військову службу», знаходяться тільки слова «у добровільному порядку/засадах».

Ділова українськи мова [не знаходить](http://dilova.at.ua/search/?q=%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%8C)

СУМ-11, Словопедія, Вікіпедія, Тлумачний словник української мови (у 20-ти томах), Загальний народний англійсько-український словник (2010– ...) та інші, в принципі надають тільки визначення

> **ДОБРОВО́ЛЕЦЬ**, льця, ч. Той, хто вступає в армію з власного бажання, добровільно. ...; // Той, хто з своєї волі береться за виконання яких-небудь обов’язків, якоїсь роботи...

І чомусь стали брати сумніви, а чи вживається дане слово в сучасній діловій українській мові чи вже - ні? Може існує якийсь синонім?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[Словник синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%8C)*** подає декілька варіантів синонімів до слова ***"доброволець"***

> **ДОБРОВО́ЛЕЦЬ** (той, хто за власним бажанням береться за виконання чогось, зокрема йде до війська), **ОХО́ЧИЙ, ОХО́ТНИК** *(заст)*.;
>   **ВОЛОНТЕ́Р** *(заст.)* (на військовій службі). *Повернувся з Європи старший син Івась, котрий пішов в армію добровольцем* (О. Бердник); *З
>   багатьох охочих ми відібрали для прикриття десять чоловік, переважно
>   гарних кулеметників* (В. Козаченко); *Ми залишили кількох охотників на
>   правдиву смерть, самі ж подалися очеретами вбік і вчасно вискочили з
>   мішка* (Ю. Яновський); *Загони волонтерів на чолі з Джузеппе
>   Гарібальді висадилися на острові Сицилія* (з газети). 
>   **ОХО́ЧИЙ** (ім.) (той, хто виявляє бажання, готовність до чого-небудь), **БАЖА́ЮЧИЙ, ОХО́ТНИК** *(розм.)* *Охочих ходити до
>   школи все більшало* (Л. Юхвід); *Бажаючі підійти до коменданта
>   штовхалися і терлися, як вівці в загороді* (Григорій Тютюнник); *-
>   Охотників багацько, а купців мало. Гуртом не спроможетеся телиці
>   купить.., - звернувся Опанас до людей* (Л. Яновська).

Оскільки в жодному словнику ([СУМ-20](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=22885&page=778), [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/dobrovolecj), [Російсько-українські словники](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%8C&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on)) не зазначено, що "доброволець" діалектне, запозичене чи застаріле, на мою думку, його можна вживати в [діловій українській мові.](http://pidruchniki.com/1099021438351/dokumentoznavstvo/ukrayinska_literaturna_mova_normi#31)